# C# WPF dynamically creating and binding comboboxes via XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I'm rather new to WPF and MVVM and now I came across a problem which I did not manage to find a solution so far. I am updating an old program which is using Windows.Forms. Since I am currently reading and learning about WPF, I thought it a good idea to redo the program in WPF.

My program reads an ASCII-File in a special format and creates a list of `Fragment` objects from it. Then the list is displayed in a dynamically created GUI. The `Fragment` object look as follows:

```
public class Fragment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }

    public int ActiveIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BitValue { get; set; }
}
```

So: Each `Fragment` can have multiple `Value` objects in the property. The active value is also read from the ASCII file and its index (index from the Value in the `List<Value>`) is saved in the `ActiveIndex` property.

I have prepared a simple XAML-Layout where the results shall be displayed.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="0, 3"></StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" IsEnabled="True" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="0, 3"></StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So: in the first StackPanel I want to display all `Fragment.Name` as Labels, in the second StackPanel I want to create a ComboBox for each `Fragment` which carries all `Fragment.Values` showing the `Value.Name` property. The `ActiveIndex` is bound to the SelectedIndex of the combobox.

I can perfectly do that in the code behind file but that would give me and everyone else, who sees that, a serious headache. I understand, that it is possible to do that in XAML, but I do not really get, how it is done.
Can anyone hint me in the correct direction who such a behaviour can be achieved? Also, if there are better GUI ways to handle that, I am completely open for suggestions. The current one ist just a simple transfer from the Windows.Forms version of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ItemsControl:

```xml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NameOfYourListOfFragments}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="0, 3"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </itemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" IsEnabled="True" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding NameOfYourListOfFragments}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <StackPanel  Margin="0, 3"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
                <Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding ActiveIndex}"/>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With `ItemsPanel`, you tell the `ItemsControl`, in which kind of Panel your GUI elements should be arranged. The `ItemTemplate` tell you, what the element in your ItemsControl look like.

If you use an `ObservableCollection`, you can also add or remove entries at runtime and the GUI will be updated automatically.

In order to make the binding fully work, it's propable that your classes also have to impelement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you have to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of your properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! That got me onto the right track! With some reading about ItemControl and some changes, it works like a charm now.